# How to delete first n characters from a binary file

Tags: c, file

I have a binary file from which I want to delete first `n` characters before further processing. I have file pointer as input.

I tried to use `ftruncate` but for that I had to create another file pointer which I don't want. I tried below code but it does not help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

        FILE*f,ftemp;
        f=fopen("./temp","a");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        fseek(f,n,SEEK_SET);
        ftruncate(fileno(f),/*end of file*/ );
        ftemp=f;
        return 0;
}
```

Please suggest any other way.

Actually the first n bytes are binary and rest of the part is like asn.

Thanks

Comment: To delete characters from a file, other than from the very end of the file, you're going to need to write the results to a new file, omitting the characters you want to delete. Or, you might be able to open the file read/write (you opened yours as append) and carefully read and write blocks of up to `n` characters, seeking back and forth, then truncate by `n` at the end of the process, which is all riskier. It's simpler and probably more efficient just to use a new file. You can't simply delete characters from the file.

Comment: I'm not sure: Do you want to actual delete the first n bytes permanently from the file, or do you want to just skip them?

Comment: i want to delete it permanently. Actually there is asn format file in which n characters are header and third party function (which i can't modify ) are unable to read it so i want to delete these characters.

Comment: i can't change name of file , since there are further checks in which it verifies file name.

Comment: but you wouldn't change the name permanently, imagine it is like having a temporary copy of it

Comment: the posted code fails to compile 1) the `#include <sys/types.h>` statement is missing.   Other problems: 1) always check (!=NUL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful 2) fturncate() removes the end of the file, not the beginning (read the man page) and always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful, 3) ftruncate() requires the file be opened for write, not opened for append

Comment: you could open the file for read, then fseek() to the desired starting location, then call the 'unchangable' function with the 'f' file pointer.  so when the 'unchangable' function starts reading, it starts at the desired position in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program which will lop off the first ***N*** bytes of ***./temp***, leaving the original file as ***./temp-old***.
It assumes the file will fit in memory.
You specify ***N*** on the command line.

```
/*
 * THIS PROGRAM IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED.
 */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define ERR (-1)

int main (
        int     argc,
        char ** argv
) {
        int             fdin;
        int             fdout;
        unsigned long   n;
        struct stat     st;
        size_t          sz;
        ssize_t         ssz;
        char *          data;

        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s nbytes\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        n = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        if (errno) {
                fprintf(stderr, "nbytes (%s) is suspect\n", argv[1]);
                return 1;
        }
        fdin = open("./temp", O_RDONLY, 0);
        if (fdin == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "open input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        if (fstat(fdin, &st) == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "stat input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        sz = st.st_size;
        if (sz < n) {
                fprintf(stderr, "file is not that big\n");
                return 1;
        }
        data = malloc(sz);
        if (data == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "insufficient memory\n");
                return 1;
        }
        ssz = read(fdin, data, sz);
        if (ssz < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        if ((size_t)ssz != sz) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read was short\n");
                return 1;
        }
        (void)close(fdin);
        fdout = open("./temp-new", O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_WRONLY, st.st_mode);
        if (fdout == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "open output: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        sz -= n;
        ssz = write(fdout, data + n, sz);
        if (ssz < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "write output: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        if ((size_t)ssz != sz) {
                fprintf(stderr, "write was short\n");
                return 1;
        }
        if (close(fdout) == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "write close: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        if (link("./temp", "./temp-old") == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "link input: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        if (rename("./temp-new", "./temp") == ERR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "rename output: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I wrote it carefully, but, of course you should make a backup copy of your file before using it, just in case...

Comment: Well validated! There are few answers as thorough. As for the cheezy lawyer weasle-words disclaimer.... the jury is still out `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dd` utility. One way is to set the block size to be equal to the number of bytes you want to delete, then tell `dd` to seek one block ahead in the input file:

```
# N is number of bytes to delete: wherever N is seen
# substitute this value.

dd if=infile of=outfile bs=N seek=1
```

Now `outfile` is a copy of `infile`, but with the first N bytes removed.

The following command will also work; unfortunately, it will perform 1 byte `read` and `write` system calls, since the block size is 1 byte:

```
# N is number of bytes to delete
dd if=infile of=outfile bs=1 seek=N
```

We can use separate input and output block sizes (`ibs` and `obs`) if N is too small to be a good buffering factor, so that at least we write in larger chunks:

```
# read N at a time, skipping first N; write 64 kB at a time:
dd if=infile of=outfile ibs=N obs=65536 seek=1
```

We can simulate an in-place deletion by then renaming `outfile` to `infile`.

It should be possible to actually do this in place. The following **almost** works:

```
dd if=inoutfile of=inoutfile bs=N conv=notrunc skip=1
```

The only problem is that without the `conv=notrunc` option, the file is immediately truncated to zero length. The content is gone! And **with** the option, the file isn't truncated at all after being written.

GNU Coreutils has a `truncate` command which can be used:

```
dd if=inoutfile of=inoutfile bs=N conv=notrunc skip=1
truncate -s -N inoutfile
```

The `-` prefix on the size argument in `truncate` means "reduce the size by that many bytes".

Comment: truncate() removes bytes at the end of the file, not the beginning.